# Java External MySQL Database Connection

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

I have a Java application that requires a connection to an external MySQL database. However, we have a restricted list of ip addresses that are able to log into the computer.The issue is one of our clients travels and therefore has a dynamic ip address. We have chosen the route to use http://www.noip.com to take into consideration the dynamic ip address. However, there's the issue on how to link the two programs together. The java application still refers to [ip address].hlrn.qwest.net rather than [sub-domain].no-ip.biz.

Is there a function I can use in Java to override what my ip address is used to connect to the database?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems this is stand alone application. Otherwise dynamic IP is irrelevant.

Comment: It's a standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the connection string should have been externalised so that it could be modified easily. If it's more of a policy constraint on IPs then I think whichever way we do it; it could still be considered a violation. Anyway, I'm assuming you have already given it a thought.

On any OS you have a HOSTS file that can be used to override DNS name resolution. The only constraint is that you can only map IPs not a hostname to another hostname. You could however alias a hostname that's already mapped to an IP. For example, if you add the below

```
127.0.0.1    [ip address].hlrn.qwest.net
```

to your HOSTS file (which by the way is located at `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows) your Java application would start making connections to the localhost only. So, you could add the following to redirect and make your Java application connect to `no-ip.biz` instead.

```
ip.add.re.ss    [sub-domain].no-ip.biz    [ip address].hlrn.qwest.net
```

To make this DNS process automatic and redirect without dealing with the actual IP is not easy and requires fiddling with your own DNS setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Conne {
    public static Connection GetConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
    {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip address /database name","username","password");
        return connection;
    }
}
```

after creating this class you can use the reference or object of this class for connection purpose....i think that will be helpful to you..... :) :)